# Convert case creation page to lightning

Tags: lightning, case, support, classic

I have enabled the lightning experience for some profiles and upgrade the existing classic app to lightning. Now when I try to create a new support case, after selecting the record type the details page that appears (case creation page) is still in classic. How can I convert this page to lightning?

Comment: is the user given access to the new Lightning app?

Comment: Have you checked this? -[Create and Configure Lightning Experience Record Pages](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.lightning_app_builder_customize_lex_pages.htm&type=5)